# Restore minimized frameless window from Taskbar

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qqmlapplicationengine

I'm creating one basic qml application with visibility:"FullScreen", and I have one button to minimize the application but after minimizing  if i click on the exe in task bar its coming with framed application with min, max, close. I want it again in FullScreen mode.

```
applicationWindow
{
id:mainWindow
visible: true
visibility: "FullScreen"
Rectangle {
    id:rect
       width: 140
       height: 140
       color: "lightblue"
       anchors.centerIn: parent

   }
  Button{
     anchors.top: rect.bottom
    anchors.left: rect.left
    text: "Minimize"
    onClicked: {
        mainWindow.showMinimized()
    }
  }
}
```

[After minimizing and trying to open from taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKi1Z.png)

Comment: As the property is a numeric enumeration shouldn't that be `Window.FullScreen` not `"FullScreen"`? See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-window.html#visibility-prop

Comment: I recommend using property binding, e.g. `visibility: visible ? Window.FullScreen : Window.Windowed`. In other words every time, `visible==true` you force the visibility back to `Window.FullScreen`.